# Is there a way to increase python time between mouse clicks

Tags: python, automation

I know I can use time.sleep(), but I need something that would affect whole script.It is automatic test homework and aplication buttons are clicked almost instantly. It is a bit anoying because I cant see if everything is working as supposed(still learning).

```
import pyautogui
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="uia").start(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\WPF_RentACar_3maj\WPFRentACar\bin\Debug\WPFRentACar.exe")
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
#app.LoginWIndow.print_control_identifiers()
dlg =app.LoginWindow
dlg.MaximizeButton.click()
dlg.MinimizeButton.click()
dlg.MaximizeButton.click()
dlg.Restore.click()
try:
   dlg.Edit1.type_keys("123")
   dlg.Edit2.type_keys("123")
   dlg.LoginButton.click()
   dlg.Button1.click()
finally:
    print("Cant login with wrong credentials!")
    time.sleep(2)
dlg.Edit1.type_keys("'^a{BACKSPACE}")
dlg.Edit2.type_keys("'^a{BACKSPACE}")
dlg.LoginButton1.click()



time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: What testing framework are you using? Can you share some example code?

Comment: I added the code @match

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep()` does stop the whole script. Or are you using threading or python 2? Also can you tell us what you are also trying to automate.

Comment: I am trying to automate login page for test aplication.Max,Min window,typing login credentials,pressing login button. But when I try ```
dlg.MaximizeButton.click()
dlg.MinimizeButton.click()
dlg.MaximizeButton.click()
dlg.Restore.click()
```
Its done almost in an instant.
I need it to wait at least 1 sec between those clicks.